# Drive API returning more response data then it used to send earlier

Tags: google-drive-api, apex

We have an integration of drive API in salesforce APEX language to retrieve the folders present on the drive. This service is up and running for a few years now and we saw no issues with, however a couple of days back we have noticed time out issues in Apex while response from google was being parsed. What we feel is that the response size has increased a lot which takes Apex a long time to parse and it ultimately times out. It was evident that this started happening with a lot of our google accounts all of a sudden and turned out that process timed out while parsing the response.
Surprisingly now the time out is not occurring, but we need to ensure was there an issue at Drive API which led to this?

The API that was hit was, https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=
mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder and trashed=false